# Unexpected handling of "variables" in cmd.exe batch file

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd

I have a `xyz.bat` file with this content:

```
@set val=one
@if "%val%" equ "one" (
   @set val=yes
   echo val after setting it: %val%
) else (
   @set val=no
)
@echo %val%
```

Running it in `cmd.exe` prints

```
val after setting it: one
yes
```

but I expected

```
val after setting it: yes
yes
```

Why is this? And is there a way to make it behave as I think it should?

Answer (score 6):

Everything between `(` and `)` is parsed as a single line (joining commands with `&`) – and the shell [expands `%var%` variables at parse time](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx)

The output of [`set /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490998.aspx) explains this further.

In recent versions:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var=one
if a equ a (
    set var=two
    echo immediate expansion: %var%
    echo delayed expansion:   !var!
)
echo after: %var%
```

- *The Old New Thing:* [Environment variable expansion occurs when the command is read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx)

---

...but that way lies madness. For example, if you want to echo a `!` in delayed expansion mode, you have to [escape it twice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/29/9914426.aspx):

```
echo hi^^!
```

(This gets parsed twice, reduced to `echo hi^!` the first time.) And don't even get me started on using `^` inside variables.

- *The Old New Thing:* [What this batch file needs is more escape characters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/29/9914426.aspx)

---

Consider a less kludgy language (Perl, Python, PowerShell, PHP, JScript, C#, ...)

Comment: "expands at parse time" .. thats the explanation, the rest is just fillup :) it is even worse in cmd.exe with "for"-constructs .. cmd.exe creates a "pseudo script in ram" out of the statements and executes that, no runtime-evaluation. depending on what OP wants to achieve in the end: i would go the jscript/vbs route, thats installed @windows per default. of coz, .py etc is just nicer, but maybe OP has some kind of plan in his head.

Comment: If delayed expansion is enabled and a ! is found, then the line is parsed two times, important for all ^ in the line, but not for the other special characters, so you escape `echo one ^& two ^^^^ three^^!` -> `one & two ^ three!`